# How do I change a Vector2?

Tags: c#, xna

So I've written a little method that does this for me, but I feel like this should already exist in some sense.

```
position = ChangeVector(250.0f + somefloat, 100.0f + someotherfloat);


public Vector2 ChangeVector(float X, float Y)
{
    Vector2 Vector = new Vector2();
    Vector.X = X;
    Vector.Y = Y;
    return Vector;
}
```

I feel like I should just be able to type something like:

```
position = (250.0f + somefloat, 100.0f + someotherfloat);
```

This is more out of curiosity than anything else, my way of doing it does work fine, it just seems messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195795.aspx) `Vector2 Constructor (Single, Single)`:

```
position = new Vector2(250.0f + somefloat, 100.0f + someotherfloat);
```

Comment: For the record, you can also just add two vectors:  `var result = position + new Vector2(250.0f, 100.0f);`